# Bitwise operations in java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, shift, operations

what does this piece of code mean ...Can anyone explain how does this work..

```
sum += (i & (1<<j)) != 0 ? n[j] : 0;
```

full code:

```
  int max = (1 << N)-1;

  //System.err.println(max);
  String res = "No";
  for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++)
  {
    long sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
      sum += (i & (1<<j)) != 0 ? n[j] : 0;
    }
    //System.err.println(i + " " + sum);
    if(sum == m){

      res = "Yes";
      break;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say that `a = 0011 1100`

So with the Binary Left Shift Operator (<<). The left operands value is moved left by the number of bits specified by the right operand.

```
A << 2 will give 240 which is 1111 0000
```

So in your code you have a loop for i and a loop for j

And this line

```
sum += (i & (1<<j)) != 0 ? n[j] : 0;
```

So for your second iteration of i = 2 and  first iteration of j = 1

First the left shift operator will shift left all bits one position, resulting in `0000 0001 << 1 = 0000 0010 (or 2)`

then you have a binary `and` comparison which will be i `(0000 0010 in binary) & (0000 0010) = 0000 0010 (or 2)`

And this `and` result will be asked if it's distinct of zero. If this result it's true then `sum` will be increased by the number in the `n[j]` array position, else will not be increased.

Java has a shortened version of an if else command. The use of it is very easy, once you understand it.

It’s written:

```
x ? y : z;
```

Here the question mark and the colon will take the place of the commands if and else.
This means:

```
condition ? inCaseOfTrue : elseCase;
```

Answer (score 2):

With this code ***i & (1 << j)*** you get ***jth bit of i*** in binary representation. And if it equals 1 then you add n[j] to sum.
The full code shows you calculate all possible sums with selecting some elememts of array n;